# RedirectToAction hangs without redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, redirecttoaction

I have the following code for registering users in my app

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Register( RegisterModel model ) {
    if ( !ModelState.IsValid ) {
        //Invalid - redisplay form with errors
        return View( model );
    }

    try {
        MembershipUser mu = _manager.RegisterUser( model );
        //Send confirmation email here
    }
    catch ( RegistrationException rex ) {
        ModelState.AddModelError( "", rex.Message );
    }
    return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home" );
}
```

If the user get correctly registered on the system I am redirecting him to the Home page of the app with

```
return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home" );
```

I have this code working in my dev box and in my staging server. But when I publish it on the production server accessible through the internet it hangs on the last call, after sending the email, without redirecting the user at all.

Any idea?

Comment: When you say it hangs, do you mean the thread hangs or that the experience for the user is one where the mail is sent but they don't see a redirect?

Comment: the second you said. It keeps the user waiting but dont redirect to the home page

Comment: So I take it that the browser is not receiving the 302 response, do you know whether it is receiving anything?

Comment: I am gonna trying using fiddler.

Comment: Lorenzo - on the remote machine, try removing the error handling. it might just be that catch ( RegistrationException rex ) is being called but swallowed, or an error with the remote email setup might just cause it to traverse another error path. difficult tho to know without seeing the returned headers (or does the page just 'remain')??

Comment: @jim: you are correct. I had temporarily disabled email...If you answer the question I am going to accept your answer... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lorenzo,

I think that you may have an error (configuration and/or disabled) with the remote mail setup and this error is being 'swallowed' in your try/catch block. Try disabling that block and you should be able to see the actual error that occurred on the server. My gut feel is that this is where the issue lies!! I've gone down this path MANY a time, so you're not alone.

The joys of switching to a 'live' environment...

cheers...